# Spring Batch Partitioning - partition step not executing

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Batch Partitioning to fetch and process records based on some range in one of the columns from the DB table. The partition step **stagingPartitionStep** appears after few steps in the job configuration as follows:

```
    <batch:job id="myBatchJob">
     <batch:step id="mainStep">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="myTaskExecutor" transaction-manager="batchTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="myDataReader"
                processor="MyDataProcessor" writer="MyDataWriter" commit-interval="50">
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="myItemListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="checkConditionStep" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="checkConditionStep">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="checkConditionExecutor"
            transaction-manager="batchTransactionManager" ref="checkConditionTasklet">
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:next on="FAILED" to="updateStagingTableStep" />
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="stagingPartitionStep" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="updateStagingTableStep">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="checkConditionExecutor"
            transaction-manager="batchTransactionManager" ref="updateStagingTasklet">
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>   
    <batch:step id="stagingPartitionStep">
        <batch:partition step="processStagingStep" partitioner="stagingProcessPartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="stagingProcessTaskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>       
<batch:job>
```

The partitioner and the partion step:

```
<bean id="stagingProcessPartitioner"
        class="com.mycom.batch.partitioner.StagingProcessPartitioner"
        scope="step"> 
</bean>

<batch:step id="processStagingStep">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="batchTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="stagingProcessorDataReader" writer="stagingProcessorDataWriter"
                commit-interval="50">
            </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>    
</batch:step>
```

The task executors:

```
<bean id="myTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
</bean>

<bean id="stagingProcessTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
</bean> 

<bean id="checkConditionStep"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1" />
</bean>
```

The partitioner implementation: The partitioner creates ExecutionContext for each partioned step and puts a prefix value which will be used in the JDBC query to create a partion based on voucher number.

```
public class StagingProcessPartitioner implements Partitioner{

 public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    for(int threadId = 0; threadId < gridSize; threadId++){
        ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
        String stepName = "step" + threadId;
        context.put("voucherSuffix", threadId);
        partitionMap.put(stepName, context);
        LOGGER.info("Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : " + stepName);
    }
    return partitionMap;
}}
```

The data reader: The voucherSuffix from the step context is used in JDBC query to create data partion. Therefore 10 partions should be created on voucher numbers ending 0,1,2....,9.

```
    <bean id="stagingProcessorDataReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" 
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider" ref="stagingDataQueryProvider" />
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="department" value="#{jobParameters[department]}" />
            <entry key="joiningDate" value="#{jobParameters[joiningDate]}" />
            <entry key="voucherSuffix" value="#{stepExecutionContext[voucherSuffix]}" />
        </map>
    </property> 
    <property name="pageSize" value="1000" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="myDataRowMapper"/>      
</bean>

<bean id="stagingDataQueryProvider"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DOB, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2" />           
    <property name="fromClause" value="EMP_STG_TBL" />
    <property name="whereClause" value="WHERE DEPT_ID=:department AND DOJ=:joiningDate AND VCHR LIKE '%:voucherSuffix'" />
    <property name="sortKeys">
        <map>
            <entry key="EMP_ID" value="ASCENDING"></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The problem is, when the job is executted, each step is executed fine till the partion step. The partioner creates the execution context which can be confirmed from the log statements but the step processStagingStep is not executed and the job finishes with status COMPLETED. Is this job and partion step configuration correct?

---

Here are the log statements

> 2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [checkConditionStep]
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 SimpleStepHandler:146 - Executing step: [stagingPartitionStep]
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step0
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step1
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step2
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step3
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step4
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step5
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step6
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step7
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step8
>   2015-02-23 03:03:04 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 StagingProcessPartitioner:29 - Created ExecutionContext for partioned step : step9
>   2015-02-23 03:03:05 INFO myTaskScheduler-3 SimpleJobLauncher:136 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=myBatchJob]] completed with the following parameters: [] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

Comment: Are the child steps being executed at all and if so, what are the results for each?  Also, how are the ids generated in the partitioner associated with the VCHR field in the database?

Comment: Yes, all the child steps completes normally and the partitioner is being invoked and I can see the logs statements being generated from partiotion method. As I need to partion the records based on voucherNumber ending with 0,1,2,..9 I am passing threadId which also ranges from 0...9 that will be used in the query.

Comment: The child step **is** processStagingStep so I'm confused since your question states that it isn't being executed but you just said it is...

Comment: The step stagingPartitionStep which calls the partitioner is executed but the partitioned step processStagingStep is not.

Comment: What is the result of each of the child StepExecutions (the ones for processStagingStep) in the job repository?

Comment: To be more precise in terms of partitioning, the master step stagingPartitionStep gets called but the slave step processStagingStep doesn't get executed.

Comment: And what does the job repository say for each of the processStagingSteps?